# Executing a macro in Excel sheet

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I would like to execute a macro (VBA Code for formatting the sheet) in an excel sheet that i create from code. The approach I use right now is put the macro in the `workbook_open`
 event and open the Excel sheet from code. That applies the formatting and I save it later. But this slows down the process a lot.

I would like to know if there is way I can execute a macro using the DocumentFormat.OpenXml SDK or some other .net class without actually opening the excel file thus improving performance.

I have gone through a lot of internet material , but all in vain. Maybe I am just too much into it that I am just overlooking a very simple solution.
Kindly advise.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to open the file if you want to format it...

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just trying to educate myself, if i do not put it in the workbook_open event and create a separate function, still I will not be able to execute it from code without opening the file?Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to just point out for reference. The comment from Tim is the answer to this, for anyone looking for an answer. I cannot mark a comment as answer so just re writing it. Will mark it as answer until I find some better way to do it.

*You'll have to open the file if you want to format it...* – Tim Williams